# Compare Word’s table column with Excel’s table column

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, compare

I have a word table like this:

[image]

And I want to compare, using VBA, the column with the different columns from a excel table that looks like this:

[image]

I want to compare the column with the other columns and highlight in red in the word column if one value is not found (it doesn’t matter that the values are in a different order in both tables).

I have found several ways to compare two tables in excel using vba but I’d like to see if it’s possible to compare one table in word with one on excel because I’m not able to do it.
Thank you so much!

Ps: I want that the macro runs from the word file because I’ll use a button to run it from the word.

Ps2: I have this code by now but I'm getting an error 450 in the line "With .Find" and I don't know why:

```
Private Sub CompararColumnas_Click()

   Dim wrdTbl As Table
    'Set your table
    With ActiveDocument
        If ActiveDocument.Tables.Count >= 1 Then
            Set wrdTbl = .Tables(InputBox("Table # to copy? There are " & .Tables.Count & " tables to choose from."))
        End If
    End With

    Dim AD_UsersPath As String
    AD_UsersPath = "C:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & "\Desktop\Comparar Columnas VBA\Animales.xlsx"
    Dim AD_USERS As Object
    Set AD_USERS = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    AD_USERS.Visible = False
    AD_USERS.Application.Workbooks.Open AD_UsersPath
    
    LastRow = ThisDocument.Tables(1).Columns(1).Cells.Count
    Dim I As Integer
    For I = 1 To LastRow
        wVal = ThisDocument.Tables(1).Cell(I, 1)
        
        With AD_USERS.Range("A:A")
            With .Find
                .Forward = True
                .Wrap = wdFindStop
                .Execute FindText:=wVal, MatchCase:=True
            End With
            Do While .Find.Found
                User = AD_USERS.Cells(.Row, 1).Text
                .Find.Execute
            Loop
        End With
        'User = AD_USERS.Cells(AD_USERS.Range("A:A").Find(what:="Perro").Row, 1).Text
        'User = AD_USERS.Cells(AD_USERS.Range("A:A").Find(What:=wVal).Row, 1).Text
        
        wrdTbl.Cell(I, 2).Range.Text = User
    Next I

End Sub
```

Comment: do you have any existing code to show? is there anything you've tried but it's not working?

Comment: It is certainly possible. You need to open your document using a `Word.Application` object, find the table and set it a variable (e.g. `tbl`). You can then loop to compare. To access a cell value you can use something like `tbl.Cell(1, 1).Range.Text`. There are plenty of resources to show you how to use vba to control word documents.

Comment: Sorry I missed your "Ps" line. But if you want to do it from word, then you simply use an `Excel.Application` object in word VBA.

Comment: @technoman23 I added a code in Ps2 where I compared two columns but from excel tables.

Comment: I see Super Symmetry, I’ll try if I can using an excel application, but I’m quite lost with it as I have always used vba only from excels.

Comment: Using word vba (or any other Office application for that matter) is not very different from using it within excel, you only need to understand the application's object model. A good place to start is the macro recorder: I find it extremely useful

Comment: Thank you! I’ll take a look to see if I’m able to do it. By now I haven’t got anything.

Comment: Instead of With .Find --- just do a loop over the range. Do you need to loop the whole of A column? or can you say reasonably, 50k rows is ok?

Comment: Hmmm I don’t get what you mean exactly, yes it can be done for 50k, even 100 rows is perfect. But I’m not sure how you mean it